Is micropython compatible with Ply?
I would like to use the ply parser on micropython.
Running lex.py in micropython gives me a syntax error.  Line 341.
def get_caller_module_dict(levels):
    f = sys._getframe(levels)
    return { **f.f_globals, **f.f_locals }  //<--- syntax error here

Also with circuitpython. No with cpython.
I use cpython 3.8.10, micropython 1.23 and circuitpython 9.2.
Any recommendations you can give me?

That line uses a feature that was introduced in CPython 3.5 - which is apparently just beyond what MicroPython supports.  If you could find an older version of ply that works with Python 3.4, it would be much more likely to work for you.

In general, non-trivial Python code will not run on MicroPython. There are sufficient syntax differences between the two languages that code compatibility is difficult.

@jasonharper . This was correct. Thanks.

This uses a feature from Python 3.5. MicroPython supports some features for Python 3.5+, but not all.
There are usually ways to rewrite the code to use a more basic. In this case you can try the following:
def get_caller_module_dict(levels):
    f = sys._getframe(levels)
    out = dict()
    out.update(f.f_globals)
    out.update(f.f_locals)
    return out

